# Random variates: Why is $Var(\bar{X}_A)+Var(\bar{X}_b) \approx (S_A^2+S_B^2)/N$?

Tags: variance

Random variates: Why is $Var(\bar{X}_A)+Var(\bar{X}_b) \approx (S_A^2+S_B^2)/N$?

Since I read that $S_A,S_B$ are sample variances which have $/N$ in them as well. So $/N$ would cancel?

However, how are those the variances then?

---

$\bar{X}_A,\bar{X}_B$ are sample means. $S_a, S_B$ are corresponding sample standard deviations.

Comment: 1) Should be $Var(\bar X_A+\bar X_B) \approx$? 2) $\bar X_A$ or $\hat X_A$ 3) $\bar X_A=?$

Comment: @user158565 They're asumed to be independent.

Comment: No notation is defined in your question, and as such the question lacks meaning.

Comment: Your title and text do not seem to match up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the random variablesin groups $A$ and $B$ are each IID with respective variances $\sigma_A^2$ and $\sigma_B^2$, you can establish that the variances of sample means are:

$$\mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_A) = \frac{\sigma_A^2}{N} \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_B) = \frac{\sigma_B^2}{N}.$$

Since the sample variances function as estimators for the true variances, you can use the approximation $S_A^2 \approx \sigma_A^2$ and $S_B^2 \approx \sigma_B^2$.  This gives you:

$$\mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_A) + \mathbb{V}(\bar{X}_B) = \frac{\sigma_A^2}{N} + \frac{\sigma_B^2}{N} \approx \frac{S_A^2}{N} + \frac{S_B^2}{N} = \frac{S_A^2 + S_B^2}{N}.$$

Assuming the data in the two groups are IID, and independent of each other, this approximation is an unbiased estimator of the true variance-sum.  Using a result in [O'Neill (2014)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2014.966589) (Result 3, p. 284) it can be shown that the approximation has variance:

$$\mathbb{V} \Bigg( \frac{S_A^2 + S_B^2}{N} \Bigg) = \frac{1}{N^3} \Bigg[ \Big( \kappa_A + \frac{N-3}{N-1} \Big) \sigma_A^4 + \Big( \kappa_B + \frac{N-3}{N-1} \Big) \sigma_B^4 \Bigg],$$

where $\kappa_A$ and $\kappa_B$ are the underlying kurtosis parameters for the two groups.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that they apply the "standard estimator to population variance".